# How to setup Wildfly clustered jms (apachemq) queue with exclusive consumer

Tags: java, jms, wildfly, cluster-computing, activemq-artemis

How to setup wildfly jms messageing in clustered enviroment to properly deliver messages in same group?
I have found property for activeMq, which resolve this problem [here](http://activemq.apache.org/exclusive-consumer.html), but I' don't now how to apply this to wildfly's jms subsystem. How to setup queue or Mdb to work in exclusive mode?

I have tried to set flag "exclusive?=true" trough jms producer like:

```
@Inject
private JMSContext context;

@Resource(mappedName = "java:/jms/queue/TestQueue?consumer.exclusive=true")
private Queue testQueue;

public void pushToQueue(String messagePayload, String messageGroup) {
try {
    Message message = context.createTextMessage(messagePayload);
    message.setStringProperty("JMSXGroupID", messageGroup);
    context.createProducer().send(processQueue, message);
} catch (JMSException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and with other aproach like:

```
@Resource(name="DefaultJMSConnectionFactory")
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

try {
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    Session  session = connection.createSession();
    Queue queue = session.createQueue("TestQueue?consumer.exclusive=true");
    Message message = session.createTextMessage(messagePayload);
    session.createProducer(queue).send(message);
} catch (JMSException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and on Mdb side:

```
@MessageDriven(name = "queueMDB", activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:/jms/queue/TestQueue?consumer.exclusive=true"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "5"),
})
public class ConsumerMdb implements MessageListener {
    ...
}
```

all without succsess. In this cases I thing the string pf queue name is not parsed as URl parameter, but the whole string represent queue name (or JNI name)

Than I tried use of 'ActiveMQQueue' class for creating a queue object (which implements interface of javax.jms.Destination)
code:

```
public void pushToQueue(String messagePayload, String messageGroup) {
    try {
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        Session  session = connection.createSession();
        ActiveMQQueue queue = new ActiveMQQueue("TestQueue?consumer.exclusive=true");
        //ActiveMQQueue queue = new ActiveMQQueue("jms.queue.TestQueue");
        Message message = session.createTextMessage(messagePayload);
        session.createProducer(queue).send(message);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

With different possible cases of queue names:

```
ActiveMQQueue queue = new ActiveMQQueue("TestQueue");

ActiveMQQueue queue = new ActiveMQQueue("TestQueue?consumer.exclusive=true");

ActiveMQQueue queue = new ActiveMQQueue("java:/jms/queue/TestQueue");

ActiveMQQueue queue = new ActiveMQQueue("jms.queue.TestQueue");
```

also withour succsess. I heve got InvalidDestinationException:

```
12:54:12,959 ERROR [stderr] (default task-37) javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Not an ActiveMQ Artemis Destination:queue://TestQueue
12:54:12,959 ERROR [stderr] (default task-37)   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQSession.createProducer(ActiveMQSession.java:293)
12:54:12,959 ERROR [stderr] (default task-37)   at org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRASession.createProducer(ActiveMQRASession.java:1082)
12:54:12,959 ERROR [stderr] (default task-37)   at si.teletech.test.eecluster.ejb.queue.Producer.pushToQueue(Producer.java:67)
12:54:12,960 ERROR [stderr] (default task-37)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
12:54:12,960 ERROR [stderr] (default task-37)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
12:54:12,960 ERROR [stderr] (default task-37)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
12:54:12,960 ERROR [stderr] (default task-37)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
12:54:12,960 ERROR [stderr] (default task-37)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
12:54:12,960 ERROR [stderr] (default task-37)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
12:54:12,960 ERROR [stderr] (default task-37)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
12:54:12,960 ERROR [stderr] (default task-37)   at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:90)
...
```

But here in exception I noticed the queue name is parsed correctly "Destination:queue://TestQueue" without URL parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I saolve it myself in some way. Clustered singleton delivery is what I needed. It works similar like exclusive consumer. The Mdb bean is deployed on all nodes of cluster servers but only on one node is active (it consuming messages). In case of node fail, Mdb is started on next node in chain (i.e failover).

```
@MessageDriven(name = "queueMDB", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "TestQueue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "5"),
    })
@ClusteredSingleton
public class ConsumerMdb implements MessageListener {
    // your mdb implementation
}
```

Reference: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Message+Driven+Beans+Controlled+Delivery